# apt upgrade mysqlserver freezes and will not upgrade (ubuntu server 20.04)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I had to kill the session and then the databases are inaccessible until I reboot the server.

When I log back in and issue ‘apt upgrade’ i get the following error.

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I run ‘dpkg --configure -a’ and get the following and then it just freezes

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 86150
```

On another tty
journalctl -xe gives this when the upgrade freezes.

```
-- The unit mysql.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 13 22:18:12 arpradio systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 582 and the job result is done.
Jan 13 22:18:13 arpradio audit[6057]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid>
Jan 13 22:18:13 arpradio kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1610572693.036:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="uncon>
```

When I reboot and login mysqld is running

I have tried the following.

```
# cp -r /etc/mysql /etc/mysql_old
# apt autoremove
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 7451
```

And we are back here with the freeze.

If I check the mysql processes I find no process 7451 but this is the output.

```
# ps aux | grep mysql
root        1679  0.0  0.0   8644  4688 ?        Ssl  22:23   0:00 dockerize -template /tmp/db.cnf.tmpl:/etc/mysql/conf.d/db.cnf /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
systemd+    2526  0.3  0.1 2446780 99836 ?       Sl   22:23   0:03 mysqld
root        7370  0.3  0.0  27940 19836 pts/0    S+   22:38   0:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst configure 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
root        7379  0.0  0.0   9756  3772 pts/0    S+   22:38   0:00 /bin/bash /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst configure 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
mysql       7657  1.9  0.5 1869164 358336 pts/0  Sl+  22:39   0:01 mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.gQukBE7GtT --socket=/tmp/tmp.KUFQmDDseF/mysqld.sock --pid-file=/tmp/tmp.KUFQmDDseF/mysqld.pid
root        7759  0.0  0.0   9032   724 pts/1    S+   22:39   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I checked the status of mysql.service

```
# systemctl status mysql.service 
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-01-13 22:38:59 CET; 17min ago
    Process: 649 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 649 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"

Jan 13 22:21:43 arpradio systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 13 22:21:45 arpradio systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Jan 13 22:38:57 arpradio systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Jan 13 22:38:59 arpradio systemd[1]: mysql.service: Succeeded.
Jan 13 22:38:59 arpradio systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: How much data do you have? From what version do you upgrade? It may take time to convert the data. Also, you can not jump over certain versions, check upgrade manual.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was upgrading from but it is now 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3. I have fixed the issue, I don't think the database size was the issue, I left it overnight last night and it was still hanging there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, what I did was while the upgrade was hanging I ran

apt update && apt upgrade

on another tty and it upgraded everything, rebooted, I checked again after reboot and everything looks good.

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:5 http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                               
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Fetched 109 kB in 1s (112 kB/s)               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@arpradio:~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@arpradio:~# ps aux | grep mysql
mysql        657  1.2  0.6 2067208 378684 ?      Ssl  23:09   0:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root        2148  0.1  0.0   9796  4784 ?        Ssl  23:11   0:00 dockerize -template /tmp/db.cnf.tmpl:/etc/mysql/conf.d/db.cnf /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
systemd+    2930  0.8  0.1 2380944 99508 ?       Sl   23:11   0:00 mysqld
root        5507  0.0  0.0   9032   732 pts/0    S+   23:12   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
root@arpradio:~# systemctl status mysql.service 
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 23:09:06 CET; 3min 26s ago
    Process: 560 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 657 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 72284)
     Memory: 419.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─657 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jan 13 23:09:04 arpradio systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 13 23:09:06 arpradio systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```